# Java + Github + Docker

Tags: java, maven, github, docker, travis-ci

I have a java project that I am hosting on GitHub. I also have a Docker file that creates an image based off of the generated war files after a build (using Maven).

What I want is for a new Docker image to be generated every time I push new code to the repo. What I am getting confused with is how will Docker build the source and add the generated .war files to the base Tomcat Docker file? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Alternatively is there a way for Travis CI to generate the war and then push it to a docker image?

Comment: Probably Docker Hub https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/

Answer (score 1):

So to fix this, I had Travis CI pull data from the repo and after the build have the docker file pull the artifacts from the target directory and push the built docker image to docker hub.

.travis.yml

```
language: java

sudo: true

services:
  - docker

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
os:
  - linux

branches:
  only:
    - master

after_success:
  - docker login -e="$DOCKER_EMAIL" -u="$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p="$DOCKER_PASSWORD"
  - docker build -t blah/blah .
  - docker push blah/blah
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image
From tomcat:8-jre8

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER "Joel"

# Copy to images tomcat path
COPY target/blah*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sacred-text-api.war
```